# Caffe layer registry error

Tags: caffe

I'm new to Caffe and I have a problem running the Caffe mnist example. The error message is as follows:

```
I0607 00:24:12.260156  3593 net.cpp:67] Memory required for data: 0
I0607 00:24:12.260167  3593 layer_factory.hpp:75] Creating layer mnist
F0607 00:24:12.260180  3593 layer_factory.hpp:79] Check failed: registry.count(type) == 1 (0 vs. 1) Unknown layer type: Data (known types: )
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fe7f99a1ea4  (unknown)
    @     0x7fe7f99a1deb  (unknown)
    @     0x7fe7f99a17bf  (unknown)
    @     0x7fe7f99a4a35  (unknown)
    @           0x494fb5  caffe::LayerRegistry<>::CreateLayer()
    @           0x49725a  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @           0x499c35  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @           0x4a9d8b  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @           0x4aa3b0  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @           0x4aa5a6  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x420af0  caffe::GetSolver<>()
    @           0x418b25  train()
    @           0x41465b  main
    @     0x7fe7f76c4a40  (unknown)
    @           0x415ac9  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've searched for solutions and tried linking against dynamic library as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325108/caffe-layer-creation-failure). However it does not work. I can see the known layers is empty. What could be the cause? Please help me out. Thanks. I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: can you post the net prototxt file you are using for training?

Comment: Finally I solved the problem simply by using cmake instead of Makefile.  Still haven't figured out why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using the original solver.prototxt, the problem seems to be you define a wrong layer in the prototxt

Comment: Welcome to SO. This better be a comment (yes, I know, you are not allowed yet).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the CMake when build the caffe from source. I also had the different types of layer mismatching. CMake will fix the al issue.