# Force Symbol References in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, include

I need to force symbol reference to member functions in Visual Studio. How can I implement that force symbol reference in Visual Studio. According to this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs(v=VS.100).aspx), I need symbols. How to make member functions of a class to be force symbols? My problem is as follow.

I have a `layer_factory.hpp` and `layer_factory.cpp`.
I created static library to link to executable project.

The class with `template<>`  in `layer_factory.hpp`has member functions and they are declared and defined in `layer_factory.hpp`. I think that is the reason, when I link that static library to executable project, `these functions are not executed.`

My problem is exactly the same as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325108/caffe-layer-creation-failure). Just that I compile and build in Visual Studio 2013.

According to the discussion in the link, I can use  /OPT:NOREF or /INCLUDE linker options on the target executable or dll. I used /OPT:NOREF, still have the same error.
I am trying to use [/INCLUDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs(v=VS.100).aspx) (Force Symbol References) and it needs symbols. I don't understand how to force symbol references to these member functions.
My source files are

layer_factory.hpp

```
#ifndef CAFFE_LAYER_FACTORY_H_
#define CAFFE_LAYER_FACTORY_H_

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "caffe/common.hpp"
#include "caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h"

namespace caffe {

template <typename Dtype>
class Layer;



template <typename Dtype>
class LayerRegistry {
 public:
     typedef shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(*Creator) (const LayerParameter&);
     typedef std::map<string, Creator> CreatorRegistry;

     static CreatorRegistry& Registry()
     {
       static CreatorRegistry* g_registry_ = new CreatorRegistry();
       return *g_registry_;
     }


  // Adds a creator.
     static void AddCreator(const string& type, Creator creator)
  {
    CreatorRegistry& registry = Registry();
    CHECK_EQ(registry.count(type), 0)
        << "Layer type " << type << " already registered.";
    registry[type] = creator;
  }

  // Get a layer using a LayerParameter.
  static shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > CreateLayer(const LayerParameter& param)
  {
    if (Caffe::root_solver()) {
      LOG(INFO) << "Creating layer " << param.name();
    }
    const string& type = param.type();
    CreatorRegistry& registry = Registry();
    CHECK_EQ(registry.count(type), 1) << "Unknown layer type: " << type
        << " (known types: " << LayerTypeListString() << ")";
    return registry[type](param);
  }

  static vector<string> LayerTypeList()
  {
    CreatorRegistry& registry = Registry();
    vector<string> layer_types;
    for (typename CreatorRegistry::iterator iter = registry.begin();
         iter != registry.end(); ++iter) {
      layer_types.push_back(iter->first);
    }
    return layer_types;
  }

 private:
  // Layer registry should never be instantiated - everything is done with its
  // static variables.
  LayerRegistry() {}

  static string LayerTypeListString()
  {
    vector<string> layer_types = LayerTypeList();
    string layer_types_str;
    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = layer_types.begin();
         iter != layer_types.end(); ++iter) {
      if (iter != layer_types.begin()) {
        layer_types_str += ", ";
      }
      layer_types_str += *iter;
    }
    return layer_types_str;
  }
};


template <typename Dtype>
class LayerRegisterer {
 public:
     LayerRegisterer(const string& type,
         shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(*creator)(const LayerParameter&))
     {
       // LOG(INFO) << "Registering layer type: " << type;
       LayerRegistry<Dtype>::AddCreator(type, creator);
     }
};


#define REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(type, creator)                                  \
  static LayerRegisterer<float> g_creator_f_##type(#type, creator<float>);     \
  static LayerRegisterer<double> g_creator_d_##type(#type, creator<double>)    \

#define REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS(type)                                             \
  template <typename Dtype>                                                    \
  shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > Creator_##type##Layer(const LayerParameter& param) \
  {                                                                            \
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new type##Layer<Dtype>(param));           \
  }                                                                            \
  REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(type, Creator_##type##Layer)

}  // namespace caffe

#endif  // CAFFE_LAYER_FACTORY_H_
```

layer_factory.cpp

```
#ifdef WITH_PYTHON_LAYER
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#endif
#include <string>

#include "caffe/layer.hpp"
#include "caffe/layer_factory.hpp"
#include "caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h"
#include "caffe/vision_layers.hpp"

#ifdef WITH_PYTHON_LAYER
#include "caffe/python_layer.hpp"
#endif

namespace caffe {


// Get convolution layer according to engine.
template <typename Dtype>
shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > GetConvolutionLayer(
    const LayerParameter& param) {
  ConvolutionParameter_Engine engine = param.convolution_param().engine();
  if (engine == ConvolutionParameter_Engine_DEFAULT) {
    engine = ConvolutionParameter_Engine_CAFFE;
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
    engine = ConvolutionParameter_Engine_CUDNN;
#endif
  }
  if (engine == ConvolutionParameter_Engine_CAFFE) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new ConvolutionLayer<Dtype>(param));
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
  } else if (engine == ConvolutionParameter_Engine_CUDNN) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new CuDNNConvolutionLayer<Dtype>(param));
#endif
  } else {
    LOG(FATAL) << "Layer " << param.name() << " has unknown engine.";
  }
}

REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(Convolution, GetConvolutionLayer);

// Get pooling layer according to engine.
template <typename Dtype>
shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > GetPoolingLayer(const LayerParameter& param) {
  PoolingParameter_Engine engine = param.pooling_param().engine();
  if (engine == PoolingParameter_Engine_DEFAULT) {
    engine = PoolingParameter_Engine_CAFFE;
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
    engine = PoolingParameter_Engine_CUDNN;
#endif
  }
  if (engine == PoolingParameter_Engine_CAFFE) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new PoolingLayer<Dtype>(param));
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
  } else if (engine == PoolingParameter_Engine_CUDNN) {
    PoolingParameter p_param = param.pooling_param();
    if (p_param.pad() || p_param.pad_h() || p_param.pad_w() ||
        param.top_size() > 1) {
      LOG(INFO) << "CUDNN does not support padding or multiple tops. "
                << "Using Caffe's own pooling layer.";
      return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new PoolingLayer<Dtype>(param));
    }
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new CuDNNPoolingLayer<Dtype>(param));
#endif
  } else {
    LOG(FATAL) << "Layer " << param.name() << " has unknown engine.";
  }
}

REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(Pooling, GetPoolingLayer);

// Get relu layer according to engine.
template <typename Dtype>
shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > GetReLULayer(const LayerParameter& param) {
  ReLUParameter_Engine engine = param.relu_param().engine();
  if (engine == ReLUParameter_Engine_DEFAULT) {
    engine = ReLUParameter_Engine_CAFFE;
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
    engine = ReLUParameter_Engine_CUDNN;
#endif
  }
  if (engine == ReLUParameter_Engine_CAFFE) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new ReLULayer<Dtype>(param));
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
  } else if (engine == ReLUParameter_Engine_CUDNN) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new CuDNNReLULayer<Dtype>(param));
#endif
  } else {
    LOG(FATAL) << "Layer " << param.name() << " has unknown engine.";
  }
}

REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(ReLU, GetReLULayer);

// Get sigmoid layer according to engine.
template <typename Dtype>
shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > GetSigmoidLayer(const LayerParameter& param) {
  SigmoidParameter_Engine engine = param.sigmoid_param().engine();
  if (engine == SigmoidParameter_Engine_DEFAULT) {
    engine = SigmoidParameter_Engine_CAFFE;
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
    engine = SigmoidParameter_Engine_CUDNN;
#endif
  }
  if (engine == SigmoidParameter_Engine_CAFFE) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new SigmoidLayer<Dtype>(param));
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
  } else if (engine == SigmoidParameter_Engine_CUDNN) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new CuDNNSigmoidLayer<Dtype>(param));
#endif
  } else {
    LOG(FATAL) << "Layer " << param.name() << " has unknown engine.";
  }
}

REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(Sigmoid, GetSigmoidLayer);

// Get softmax layer according to engine.
template <typename Dtype>
shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > GetSoftmaxLayer(const LayerParameter& param) {
  SoftmaxParameter_Engine engine = param.softmax_param().engine();
  if (engine == SoftmaxParameter_Engine_DEFAULT) {
    engine = SoftmaxParameter_Engine_CAFFE;
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
    engine = SoftmaxParameter_Engine_CUDNN;
#endif
  }
  if (engine == SoftmaxParameter_Engine_CAFFE) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new SoftmaxLayer<Dtype>(param));
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
  } else if (engine == SoftmaxParameter_Engine_CUDNN) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new CuDNNSoftmaxLayer<Dtype>(param));
#endif
  } else {
    LOG(FATAL) << "Layer " << param.name() << " has unknown engine.";
  }
}

REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(Softmax, GetSoftmaxLayer);

// Get tanh layer according to engine.
template <typename Dtype>
shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > GetTanHLayer(const LayerParameter& param) {
  TanHParameter_Engine engine = param.tanh_param().engine();
  if (engine == TanHParameter_Engine_DEFAULT) {
    engine = TanHParameter_Engine_CAFFE;
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
    engine = TanHParameter_Engine_CUDNN;
#endif
  }
  if (engine == TanHParameter_Engine_CAFFE) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new TanHLayer<Dtype>(param));
#ifdef USE_CUDNN
  } else if (engine == TanHParameter_Engine_CUDNN) {
    return shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(new CuDNNTanHLayer<Dtype>(param));
#endif
  } else {
    LOG(FATAL) << "Layer " << param.name() << " has unknown engine.";
  }
}

REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(TanH, GetTanHLayer);

#ifdef WITH_PYTHON_LAYER
template <typename Dtype>
shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> > GetPythonLayer(const LayerParameter& param) {
  Py_Initialize();
  try {
    bp::object module = bp::import(param.python_param().module().c_str());
    bp::object layer = module.attr(param.python_param().layer().c_str())(param);
    return bp::extract<shared_ptr<PythonLayer<Dtype> > >(layer)();
  } catch (bp::error_already_set) {
    PyErr_Print();
    throw;
  }
}

REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(Python, GetPythonLayer);
#endif

// Layers that use their constructor as their default creator should be
// registered in their corresponding cpp files. Do not register them here.
}  // namespace caffe
```

Comment: No different. My question is not for template definition in header file. My problem is how to force symbol reference for those member functions to the exe project.

Comment: I found some discussions here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991927/how-to-force-inclusion-of-an-object-file-in-a-static-library-when-linking-into-e#). I'll test.